# Vagrant + puppet + mysql + php very slow

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm just created a vagrant machine with virtualbox for my developer environment, but for pages who make MySQL queries the execution is very slow.

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and PHP 5.6.

My Vagrantfile below:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Box
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Network
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true

  # Shared Folders
  config.vm.synced_folder "/vagrant/guest/var/www", "/var/www", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data", 
    mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 3306 

  # Provider
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 2
    v.cpuexecutioncap = 90
  end

  # Provision (Puppet)
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet| 
    puppet.module_path  = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests" 
    puppet.manifest_file = "base.pp" 
  end 

end
```

Comment: What is slow? Network latency between the guest and the host? PHP execution? Database access?

Comment: And puppet won't affect the execution speed of your code, it's there to provision the VM.... once the VM is provisioned, puppet has nothing further to do until the next time you start your VM again

Comment: @MarkBaker the vm are runnin on localhost, so there is no network latency.

Comment: There is network latency between the guest and the host, as you'll see if you use your browser's debug tools to look at performance

Comment: what have you set your domain names to ? are you using .local or .dev or something else ? you might be suffering from external DNS when you want to be using internal DNS, see a good article on serverfault - http://serverfault.com/questions/478365/routing-a-host-to-vagrant